# Update field by typecasting another using timezones

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a model, where we'll we've introduced `start_time` as a field. I now want to use the `start_date` to populate that field.

I'm not that great at SQL, so there are 2 concepts that I'm struggling with:

1) Casting the date to a time using the a timezone.

2) Getting out the timezone in the same query.

Here's what I managed to piece together so far. It executes without any errors, but also doesn't seem to do anything.

```
UPDATE campaigns
SET start_time = (
  date (campaigns.start_date + interval '0 hour') AT TIME ZONE u.timezone
)
FROM users AS u
WHERE campaigns.start_time IS NULL AND campaigns.start_date IS NOT NULL AND u.id = campaigns.user_id
```

Comment: How are `start_date`, `start_time` and `users.timezone` defined?

Comment: Cannot confirm, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c5e9/1/0

Comment: @OlafDietsche start_time is a DateTime, start_date is a Date, users.timezone is a tring (eg 'Europe/London')

Comment: There is no datetime data type in Postgres, only date, time and timestamp. When I use `start_date date, start_time timestamp`, I still cannot confirm any problems with your update statement.